# Error migrating data using Data migration tool 2.0.7

Tags: database, error, migration

I am migrating from **Magento 1.9.3** to **2.0.7** using the data migration tool and I get the following error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1142 CREATE command denied to user
>   sourceUser @'localhost' for table 'mg_m2_cl_ catalog_compare_item',
>
> **query was:** CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mg_m2_cl_catalog_compare_item`
>   ( `catalog_compare_item_id` int NOT NULL COMMENT
>   'Catalog_compare_item_id' , `operation` text NULL COMMENT 'Operation'
>   , `processed` bool NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Processed' , PRIMARY
>   KEY (`catalog_compare_item_id`) )
>   COMMENT='mg_m2_cl_catalog_compare_item' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8
>   COLLATE=utf8_general_ci

My database user configuration is as suggested in the `config.xml`

```
<!--
Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
-->
```

My source and database path are in the same instance, same user exists in both source and destination with select permission in the source database and full permissions on the destination database.

Tried using different users for source and database path and **the Error is for the source database**. It looks like the migration tool is creating tables in the source database which is not expected. Why is the tool creating tables in the source db? Do I have to grant permissions for CREATE in the source database. My biggest concern is would it create conflicts in the source db?

Comment: Please, the next question, try to formatting it properly, avoid the repetitions of words and explain at best.